# Angular pass method to directive

Tags: angular

I have a directive that I wish to pass the `(scroll)` method to.
Currently, the directive is declared as this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" pyb-fixed-table #container>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<div class="table-responsive" (scroll)="onScroll" pyb-fixed-table #container>
```

But that just expects a function in the **component** rather than the `pyb-fixed-table` directive.
How can I get the method to execute in the directive instead of the component?

Comment: Adding a @HostListener('scroll') in directive?

Comment: that listens to the whole document right? Not just the element?

Comment: No, it should listen to scroll events just on the element on which the directive is applied. Just like a click or hover events

Answer (score 0):

reference to this directive if it has export,

```
<div class="table-responsive" #pubFixed="pyb-fixed-table" pyb-fixed-table #container>
```

and call it's method

```
<div class="table-responsive" (scroll)="pubFixed.onScroll" pyb-fixed-table #container>
```